# how to create regex for password validation

Tags: java, regex, validation, passwords

It is at least 7 characters and any one of (number OR capital case OR special character) should be there.

Requirment is:
1) Password must be at least of 7 characters
2) It should contain any one of number OR capital case OR special character.

For example my password can be:

```
Testertest
testing6
Tester@ok
```

I tried like this but it is not working:

```
^(?=.*\\d)|(?=.*[a-zA-Z])|(?=.*[!@#\$%&\*]).{7,20}$
```

Comment: How do you define special character? Did you try to solve it yourself?

Comment: all special character are allowed. i tried like this 

^(?=.*\\d)|(?=.*[a-zA-Z])|(?=.*[!@#\$%&\*]).{7,20}$ 

but not working

Comment: Why limit it to max 20 characters? Have a minimum, but allow a person to have as long a password as wanted. (I have some > 20 chars now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```
^(?=.*?[\\dA-Z!@#$%&*]).{7,20}$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lC5aL2

Comment: @downvoter: If you read OP's question this is correct answer.

Comment: "a" is not a capital letter, special character, or number.

Comment: password should be valid if any one of (number OR capital case OR special character) How can I achieve this, can you please help me.

Comment: @tenub: That is how OP had it in the attempt shown (in comments) and password can very well have lower case letters.

Comment: Yet the first sentence makes it very clear. Even before the edits.

Comment: It does work for `testing6` (If using online tester replace `\\d` by `\d`)

Comment: So does `testingtesting` and `test`.

Comment: I have also added online demo for verification.

Comment: @tenub: Probably leading/trailing space in copy/paste operation may be otherwise this regex is working fine.

Comment: @PushpakJain: Glad to know it worked, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.